# Making calculated column fo weeknum in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Im using sharepoint 2007, and there is no weeknum function built-in.
how can I add calculated column in sharepoint list to show weeknum of date in another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a formula to show a weeknum in sharepoint (no built-in function).

```
=IF(ROUNDUP((ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)-(DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))+WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))))/7,0)>52,1,ROUNDUP((ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)-(DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))+WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))))/7,0))
```

the formula returns always up to 52 weeks, and the week that has 1st January is the first week in a year.
the week starts on a weekday depended on your SP server settings.

if you need to use the 53 weeks standart, use this part only

```
=ROUNDUP((ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)-(DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))+WEEKDAY((DATE(YEAR(ROUNDDOWN([Date],0)),1,1))))/7,0)
```